# Load next batch during training step

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have a TensorFlow setup that looks something like this:

```
for b in batch_loader.iter_batches(self.TRAINING_SET):
    ...
    self.session.run(train_step, feed_dict=...)
```

The `iter_batches` function loads image data from numpy memory map files into RAM. Measurements showed that the loading of data from disk takes about 1/3 of the time of running that `train_step`. Also, the `train_step` operation does not need to access the hard drive at all.

So I could make everything faster if I could load the next batch `i+1` while I'm training with batch `i`.

Can I use some python multiprocessing library for this or does TensorFlow offer something for this use case? I looked around their documentation but did not find anything. Is there a canonical way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup queues using `tf.train.start_queue_runners` and `tf.train.Coordinator`.  See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/reading_data/index.html) for details.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, basically [this](https://gist.github.com/eerwitt/518b0c9564e500b4b50f)